# Basic authentication in ELK Stack

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-x-pack

I am trying to enable basic authentication in our ELK Stack. The below steps have tried to enable the authentication

```
1. docker run -d -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.1
2. docker exec -it stoic_darwin /bin/bash
3. In side the container executed # bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca
4. No password entered and exited from the container.
5. Copied the generated file to host system - docker cp stoic_darwin:/usr/share/elasticsearch/elastic-stack-ca.p12 .
6. Updated the docker-compose file as below.

version: '3'

services:

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch
      - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.type=PKCS12
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path=elastic-stack-ca.p12
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path=elastic-stack-ca.p12
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.type=PKCS12
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - ./elastic-stack-ca.p12:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elastic-stack-ca.p12
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.10.1
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: "http://elasticsearch:9200"
      ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME: "kibana"
      ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD: "kibana"
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
7. # docker-compose up -d elasticsearch
8. But it fails with below errors.

elasticsearch    | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.loadSSLConfigurations(SSLService.java:524) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch    | ElasticsearchSecurityException[failed to load SSL configuration [xpack.security.transport.ssl]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[failed to initialize SSL TrustManager - not permitted to read truststore file [/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elastic-stack-ca.p12]]; nested: AccessDeniedException[/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elastic-stack-ca.p12];
elasticsearch    | Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elastic-stack-ca.p12
elasticsearch    |      at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
elasticsearch    |      at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
elasticsearch    |      at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
elasticsearch    |      at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:218)
elasticsearch    | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.<init>(SSLService.java:142) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch    | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin.createSSLService(XPackPlugin.java:455) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch    | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin.createComponents(XPackPlugin.java:288) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch    | "at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.lambda$new$15(Node.java:553) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.1.jar:7.10.1]",
elasticsearch    | "at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch    | "at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch    | "at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch    |      at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:375)
```

I believe to enable the basic authendiation with ELK requires the SSL certificate to connect with single/multiple clusters. So how can i resolve this error?

And also is there way to generate the cerfiticate`Performed at step-3` and to setup the build-in users password using `bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive` command in docker-compose itself?

(Or) if there any simple way to enable authentication through docker compose ll be helpful. Pls help me with the steps. thanks in advance.

Above error was due to permission have modified the permission and fixed it. Now my `logstash` contentiously throwing below erorrs.

```
logstash         | [2021-01-27T06:27:42,365][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/_xpack'"}
logstash         | [2021-01-27T06:27:42,738][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :error=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/'"}
logstash         | [2021-01-27T06:28:12,358][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/_xpack'"}
logstash         | [2021-01-27T06:28:12,753][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :error=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/'"}
logstash         | [2021-01-27T06:28:42,366][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/_xpack'"}
logstash         | [2021-01-27T06:28:42,766][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :error=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/'"}
```

In my `logstash conf` file `output section` already have provided authentication credentials.

```
output {
   elasticsearch {
     action => "index"
     hosts => "http://elasticsearch:9200"
     index => "project-info"
     user => "elastic"
     password => "password"
```

Comment: There's a good tutorial in the official documentation to achieve what you need: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/configuring-tls-docker.html

Comment: @Val, Ok thanks I will check it. It looks it uses trail based license and vailed for 30days. So basic authentication using xpack not there for free?

Comment: Yes, basic license is free forever

Comment: thanks Val, this erorr `Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:` was due to permission have resolved and enabled the kibana authentication.

Comment: Cool, good to hear

Comment: @Val, my log-stash shows `401` error repeatedly showing errors have updated more details in question. please suggest to solve it.

Comment: Have you gone through the tutorial I've linked to?

Comment: yes fixed after adding `xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username & xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password`